# std::set is giving errors after g++ compilation

Tags: c++, g++

I'm trying to find a solution for some problem (Given an array A[] of n numbers and another number x, determine whether or not there exist two elements in A whose sum is exactly x.)
This is my solution :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>

#include "stdio.h"

using std::cout;
using std::vector;

bool hasPairWithSum(vector<int> data, int sum);

int main()
{   
    int testCases;
    std::cin >> testCases;
    int arrSize;
    int sum;
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    vector<int> vec;

    for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
      std::cin >> arrSize;
      std::cin >> sum;

      for (int j = 0; j < arrSize; j++)
      {
        int tmp;
        std::cin >> tmp;
        vec.push_back(tmp);
      }
      bool result = hasPairWithSum(vec, sum);
      if (result)
        results.push_back("YES");
      else results.push_back("NO");
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < results.size(); k++)
      cout << results[k]<< std::endl;

    return 0;
}

bool hasPairWithSum(vector<int> data, int sum) {
    std::set<int> compl;
    for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++) {
        int currentCompl = sum - data[j];
        if (compl.find(data[j]) != compl.end())
            return true;
        compl.insert(currentCompl);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm using c++. Locally it works fine but with the websites online compilator (it uses g++ 5.4) it gives the following error:
`prog.cpp: In function 'bool hasPairWithSum(std::vector, int)':
prog.cpp:45:21: error: expected class-name before ';' token
  std::set compl;
                     ^
prog.cpp:48:12: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
   if (compl.find(data[j]) != compl.end())
            ^
prog.cpp:48:35: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
   if (compl.find(data[j]) != compl.end())
                                   ^
prog.cpp:50:8: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
   compl.insert(currentCompl);
        ^`

**Anyone has any idea how I can fix my solution to make in compilable in g++ ?**
Thank you!

Comment: `std::set compl;` needs a template argument, like `std::set<int> compl;` or something. edit: although it seems to have one in your code? Did you click Save?

Comment: The error message does not correspond with the shown code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik when I run it here : http://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/key-pair/0 
I get this error.

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow.com is not a help desk for some other web site.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm not asking help in problem solving, I'm asking about the problem related to compilation error in g++ compiler.

Comment: And the compilation error does not correspond with the shown code, and, unfortunately, the mind ray-beam machine in the office is not working, at the moment, and we can't figure out why the compiler used by some other web site is reporting an error that does not match the code. Or, perhaps, you copy-pasted the actual error message, and the template reference got misparsed as HTML, and thus got corrupted. What part of "the compilation error does not correspond to the shown code" is unclear?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for your responses. Other people already answered my question it was because of the `compl` is the keyword in C++ and I used it as a variable name. I don't have this compiler on my machine and that's why I pasted error from that website. I'm not very familiar with C++ just using it to solve some coding exercises, so sorry for my question and again thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that [`compl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) is a C++ keyword. Use a different identifier.

Answer (score 4):

You're running into the little-known alternate way to spell operators.  For some keyboards around the world, certain special keys are hard to type so there are names for the operators that have the same meaning (and are parsed the same) as the more normal operators.  Most code doesn't use them.

Here's the list of alternate tokens the parser knows:

```
and, and_eq, bitand, bitor, compl, not, not_eq, or, or_eq, xor, xor_eq
```

compl is another way to spell ~ and is the bitwise compliment operator.

**Just rename your variable to something else**